how to prove uncountable infinite pigeonhole principle?
Can it be proven using the pigeonhole principle that if set
A is an uncountable family of finite sets, it contains an uncountable subfamily all of whose elements have cardinality
n?
The idea is borrowed from here.
What is the Infinite Pigeonhole Principle?
If we uncountably many pigeons and put them in finitely many pigeonholes, then some pigeonhole must contain uncountably many pigeons, this hole say B;
to partition B again into sets contains only n finite elements, it can be expressed as 1=n*k for some infinite k, and since it seems that k must be 1, it reasonable to conclude that there are uncountably many sets contains n elements.

is this reasoning correct?
how to prove infinite pigeonhole principle in above link?


When you say "all of whose elements have cardinality $n$", you mean "whose elements all have the same cardinality", right? Not that we can pick any $n$ we want and it will be true?

@MartianInvader I means "all elements have same cardinal n". sry

For $n \in \mathbb N$, let $A_n = \{S \in A \mid |S| = n\}$ (I'm including $0$ in $\mathbb N$).  Thus $A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$.  If all $A_n$ were countable, $A$ would be the union of countably many countable sets, and therefore would be countable.  Thus some $A_n$ must be uncountable.

Maybe you want a union there and not an intersection.

Oops, thanks (editing)

Maybe it should be "$|S|=n$" in the brackets ?

Oops and thanks again (editing)
